# Java FileWriter skip files

Tags: java, filewriter

I have a package with files : "100.txt" ,"1000.txt", "10000.txt","100000.txt", "1000000.txt".
But when i launch my program, it skips 100 and 1000 txt files. Can you tell me why?

```
public void generateData(Path path) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
            for (int j = 100; j <= 1000000; j*=10){
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(path.resolve(Integer.toString(i)).resolve(j + ".txt").toFile());
                Random random = new Random();
                for (int k = 0; k < j; k++){
                    int num = random.nextInt(10);
                    fileWriter.write(num);
                    fileWriter.write("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and everything seemed to run pretty well.

All files were printed:

- 100.txt
- 1000.txt
- 10000.txt
- 100000.txt
- 1000000.txt

One thing I noticed is that you don't close your `FileWriter` after you're done with it.  Perhaps that is the problem.

Here is the full code I ran.  I did remove the writing of the files into the numbered directories since those directories didn't exist on my machine.

```
package forloop;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Random;

public class GenerateData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Path path = Paths.get("");

        generateData(path);
    }

    public static void generateData(Path path) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
            for (int j = 100; j <= 1000000; j*=10){
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(path.resolve(j + ".txt").toFile());
                Random random = new Random();
                for (int k = 0; k < j; k++){
                    int num = random.nextInt(10);
                    fileWriter.write(num);
                    fileWriter.write("\n");
                }
                fileWriter.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Based on Andy's suggestion a solution that uses a try-with-resources.

```
package forloop;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Random;

public class GenerateData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Path path = Paths.get("");

        generateData(path);
    }

    public static void generateData(Path path) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 100; j <= 1000000; j*=10) {
                try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(path.resolve(j + ".txt").toFile())) {
                    Random random = new Random();
                    for (int k = 0; k < j; k++){
                        int num = random.nextInt(10);
                        fileWriter.write(num);
                        fileWriter.write("\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using try-with-resources has some advantages here -- `try ( FileWriter filewriter = ... ) { ... }`. It guarantees the writer gets closed however control exits the block. And makes the lifetime clear at a glance.

Comment: @AndyThomas using a try-with-resources is for sure a better solution.  Added a second example that does just that!